# AWS sdk java filter snapshots by date

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to filter the snapshots which are greater than a certain date.
The code that I have so far is below.

```
                DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");//"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
                List<Filter> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                filterList.add(new Filter().withName("tag:brms_instance").withValues(instance.getInstanceId()));
                filterList.add(new Filter().withName("start-time").withValues(">"+dtfOut.print(new DateTime())));
                DescribeSnapshotsRequest snapshotsRequest = new DescribeSnapshotsRequest()                  
                        .withFilters(filterList);
```

The problem is that the date comparison is not working and the result is an empty snapshots array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't "new DateTime()" is always the current time? so, when you filter for ">current time" there will be none.

Comment: I have used just the date part of it, so snapshots created after the start of the day should be returned